# Login page shows briefly even if user is logged into .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I implemented login flow using `AppShell` in my .NET MAUI app by placing the `LoginPage` at the top before any flyout items -- see below:

```
...
<ShellContent
   Route="LoginPage"
   ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate login:LoginPage}"
   FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"/>

<FlyoutItem Title="My First Item">
...
```

First, I was handling the check to see if the user is already logged-in in the `OnAppearing()` method of `LoginPage.xaml.cs` but with this approach, the `LoginPage` would still display briefly even if the user was alread logged in, then the user would be forwarded to the `FirstItemPage` as defined in the app shell.

Then I decided to move the code to check if the user is logged in to `OnAppearing()` method of `AppShell.xaml.cs` but I still see the login page briefly even though I'm already logged in.

This is not a show stopper but it's not a great user experience. What am I missing here to make sure that a user who's already logged in to my app doesn't see the `LoginPage` at all when he comes back to use the app and goes straight to the page indicated in the flyout menu?

Answer (score 0):

Remove LoginPage from AppShell's hierarchy.

Then navigate like this. In app.xaml.cs:

```cs
if (notLoggedIn)
    MainPage = new LoginPage();
else
    MainPage = new AppShell();
```

On LoginPage, after successful login:

```cs
    MainPage = new AppShell();
```

If user logs out, get out of AppShell:

```cs
    MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

---

SIDE NOTE:

If you don't allow user into the app until you've talked to server to validate login, then its important to have a "landing page" that appears promptly. REASON: Device OS will kill app if it takes too long to view first page.

One way to do this is to have the login page show something appropriate if they have *previously* successfully logged in. While you wait for server response.

Comment: Thanks. This will work but I'm still confused. I was following James M.'s approach as he demonstrated in this video. In his case, it seems to work fine https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylbgWHB_gMI

Comment: You may have hit a "regression" in Maui. Probably worth filing an issue at maui github, explaining that it worked in XF, as seen in that video. If you only tested on "Local Machine" (Windows), then please test on Android also.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me.

if (isUserLoggedIn)
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//AfterLoginLandingPage");